# Where are WPRFLAG and _WINMAIN_ macros defined?

Tags: visual-c++, entry-point, winmain

You know,

there are codes like

```
#ifdef WPRFLAG
```

and

```
#ifdef _WINMAIN_
```

in `ctrexe.c` . I'm using vs2010)

These macros determine what function is called from entry point.

But I can't find these macros even in the macro settings of project setting.

Where teh hell are these macros defined?

Answer (score 3):

VS
Project->Configuration properties->Linker->System->SubSystem:

1. Console (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`)
2. Windows (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`)

`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` this let it run into `_WINMAIN_`.

Answer (score 2):

`WPRFLAG` is defined in many wide char version of source files, such as wcrt0.c under source code folder of CRT. `_WINMAIN_` is defined in Windows version of CRT source files, such as `Wincrt0.c` and `wWincrt0.c`.